# .NET Core and type equality

Tags: .net-core

This test:

```
[Fact]
public void X()
{
    Assert.IsType<Expression<Func<int>>>(Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(Expression.Constant(1)));
}
```

Runs on .NET Framework, but fails on .NET Core (3.1 in my case) with the following error:

```
Expected: System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[[System.Func`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
Actual:   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression0`1[[System.Func`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
```

Why is this? And can I do something to compare the types properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Incorrect** version of my answer before:

> Assuming the behavior for .Net Core is the same or similar to framework, here is my reasoning.
>
> Looking at the [reference source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/LambdaExpression.cs,2f4213e9640ba785,references) `Expression.Lambda<T>` creates a runtime type of `Expression<T>`, see `typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType`.
>
> `typeof(Expression<T>)` however is the compile time type.

Using the following LINQPad script you see the difference in the output

```cs
var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Int32>>(Expression.Constant(1));
exp.GetType().BaseType.Dump();
// System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`1[System.Int32]]
typeof(Expression<Func<Int32>>).BaseType.Dump();
// System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression
```

For .Net Framework an instance of [Expression<T>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/LambdaExpression.cs,349) is returned from `Expression.Lambda<T>(Expression exp)` as expected.

**But for** .Net Core the behavior was changed!

For .Net Core either [Expression<TDelegate>.Create](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/634b3484262cc4bc288c605cb1e6374cc76655a0/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/LambdaExpression.cs#L278) or [ExpressionCreator<TDelegate>.CreateExpressionFunc](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/634b3484262cc4bc288c605cb1e6374cc76655a0/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/LambdaExpression.cs#L311) is called along the way but in both cases - for this example here - a new instance of `Expression0{T} : Expression{T}` is returned! Which are obviously not of the same type.

#### to assert your type you may use

```cs
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(Expression.Constant(1));
// extract the type of used generics
var genericArgs = expression.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
// TODO: assert that we DO have exactly one argument here
Assert.IsType<Func<int>>(genericArgs[0]);

// another assert:
// unverified, but `(expression is Expression<Func<int>> _).Dump();` returns `true` in LINQPad
Assert.True(expression is Expression<Func<int>>);
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I still don't understand why this change was introduced. It is a little surprising to work with when reflecting over expressions. But that `expression.GetType()` is of a derived type of the `typeof(Expression<Func<int>>)` is a good catch. `Assert.True(expression is Expression<Func<int>>);` or `Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Expression<Func<int>>>(expression);` seems like the way ahead.